# JSON get value at first index

Tags: json

I am stuck at this and have no idea to get the script clear. See this PHP code:

```
<?php

$arr = array();

$i = 0;

while($i < 10) {
   $arr[] = $i;
   $i = $i + 1;
}

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

It will be returned like this to AJAX function :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Suppose it is stored in `d` javascript variable then how can i point to only first value so, it stores `0` to any variable.

If i do like this:

```
success: function(d) {
    var a = d[0];
}
```

It returns null.

I don't know how to explain my question because i am not good at english.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
success: function(d){
    $.each(d, function(x,y){
       var a = y['field'];
    });
}
```